# Hightlight substring of "text" in HTML SELECT OPTION using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `html-select` which gets populated at run time.
i.e. when i type something in html input textbox, i display the substring based results in below attached `html-dropdown-listbox`.

Now i want to highlight only that substring of an item in html dropdown listbox which matches with the string in html-input textbox.

e.g.
if i type "ample" in html-input textbox then it should highlight "ample"
  `<OPTION value=723.1> S*ample* Text </OPTION>`

i have already tried to modify the innerHTML property of that html-dropdown-listbox.
I want to do it using javascript.

Comment: the example i used is like this-- one of the option in html-listbox is <option value=123>Sample text</option> and if i type "ample" in html input textbox then it should highlight only "ample" of "Sample text" on the web page.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot style the inside elements of a SELECT. It's rendered by the OS, not HTML.

Comment: Well, these days the browser renders it; I think you have to go back as far as IE3/Netscape4 to find native OS widgets. But they limit the effects you can apply, and selecting a substring definitely isn't one of the options.

Comment: I bet IE still does :) But yes, this is one of the sadly forgotten elements that needs to be modernized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
<p id="textindrop">this is the text in the dropbox</p>
<a href="#" onClick="highlightsubstring('textindrop'); return false;">tohighlight</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function highlightsubstring(el) {
var theText = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
theText = theText.replace(/(web)/gi, "<b>$1</b>");
document.getElementById(el).innerHTML = theText;
}
</script>
```

Try this and see this helps you, put some logic of yours also. you can also use regular expressions for this. read about regular expression in  javascript

Comment: well .. i tried this approach !But the problem is the innerHTML just simply have <b></b> tags ... it does not interpret as BOLD font.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS3 way:

- Use `font-family: monospace` to get equal width characters.
- Use `background-image` to get an adjustable background.
- Use `background-position` to set the starting position of the highlighting background in [`ch`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ch-unit).
- Use `background-size` to set the length of the highlighting background in `ch`.

Restrictions:

- Only works in Gecko-based browsers.
- Highlighting in the `select` too requires additional adjusting. (I did it with `text-indent`, finding better solution is encouraged.)

I put together a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eEEsZ/2/) on jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks! i will take a look at the simple demo.

Comment: This is really a nice solution. But again it has limitations in IE 6.0 browser. IE replaces " character with \" so the javascript code could not add <span class="<class name>" >textbox.value<\span>.
The problem is IE does not allow to keep " character as it is.

Comment: @wardhan, are you sure your comment belongs to _this_ answer?

Comment: Yes..because i have used the idea of span class. But i faced the problem which i mentioned in above comment.